# How do I convert String of months, such as "January", "February", into a integer value?

Tags: java, date, variables, enums

I have a project called Incidents that have the following variables, value, month, year and postcode. I have opted to write my month variable of type String due to preference but am aware that some people prefer to write it as an integer. I was wondering how I would write that? At the moment I just have simple accessor and mutator methods for each of those instances, so would I need to write a new method to convert it? Would I use parseInt, and how does the syntax work, or do I use a java library? My main issue is figuring out how the syntax works.

Comment: Define your constants in an `enum`

Comment: Look into using an `enum` for your months. That way you could easily retrieve either the full name, the abbreviation, or the ordinal number.

Comment: Java has a built in enum: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html

Comment: Use HashMap<String, Integer>()

Comment: You are correct that it is incorrect to store month as a string. What you need is a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) for both year and month. This will give you a string or an int without much trouble. It can parse a string or be created from a `Year` and a `Month` object.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8+, you can use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

Unfortunately, `Month` doesn't provide a `parse` method, like most of the other `java.time` classes, however, if you look at the implementation of the [`getDisplayName(TextStyle style, Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method, you'll find:

```
public String getDisplayName(TextStyle style, Locale locale) {
    return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(MONTH_OF_YEAR, style)
            .toFormatter(locale)
            .format(this);
}
```

So to parse we can create our own method, using the same kind of formatter, like this:

```
public static Month parseMonth(CharSequence text, TextStyle style, Locale locale) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, style)
            .toFormatter(locale);
    return Month.from(fmt.parse(text));
}
```

*Examples*

```
String s = Month.OCTOBER.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);
System.out.println(s); // prints: October

Month month = parseMonth("October", TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);
System.out.println(month); // prints: OCTOBER
System.out.println(month.getValue()); // prints: 10
```

---

In Java <8, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the text:

```
public static int parseMonth(String text) {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.US);
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(fmt.parse(text));
        return cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month: " + text);
    }
}
```

*Example*

```
int month = parseMonth("October");
System.out.println(month); // prints: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Something of an aside, but if you use enums, you can also do a look-up based on the name of the enum.

For example, an enum like

```
public enum MyMonth {January, February, March, April, May }
```

You can do this

```
MyMonth month = MyMonth.valueOf("February");
```

to get the enum for the month named "February."

To get the "month number" you can use the `ordinal()` method:

```
  MyMonth month = MyMonth.valueOf("February");
  System.out.println( month.ordinal() );
```

Since Java enums are zero based, this prints "1" for February.  You'll have to remember to add one if you want January to start at one.

Using an integer can be handy for iterating over all of your months (or any other enum) but with the `values()` static method you don't need to:

```
 for( MyMonth m : MyMonth.values() ) 
    System.out.println( m );
```

These lines of code will print all of the month names defined in the `MyMonth` enum.

Here's the link to the full docs.  A lot of people don't know this because it's buried in a somewhat obscure section of the JLS and isn't directly referenced in the API docs.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9

```
In addition, if E is the name of an enum type, 
then that type has the following implicitly declared 
static methods:

/**
* Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
* used to iterate over the constants as follows:
*
*    for(E c : E.values())
*        System.out.println(c);
*
* @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared
*/
public static E[] values();

/**
* Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified
* name.
* The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare
* an enum constant in this type.  (Extraneous whitespace 
* characters are not permitted.)
* 
* @return the enum constant with the specified name
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if this enum type has no
* constant with the specified name
*/
public static E valueOf(String name);
```

Comment: Fixed typos, it compiles and runs for me.

Comment: Just a note: the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) do specifically state: Do not use `ordinal()` to obtain the numeric representation of Month. Use `getValue()` instead.

Comment: Just so everyone is on the same page, I'm talking about the OP defining their own enum, not using the class from `java.time.Month`.  I probably should have used the name `MyMonth` to make this clear.  (Also: what I'm saying is **this is what you get for free just by defining an enum.**  No code required.  If you need more, fine, but the Java language gives you all of the above for free.)

Answer (score 1):

Java has a built-in `enum` that handles this for you in the `java.time` package.

You can use it like so:

```
import java.time.Month;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Use sample month of April
        Month month = Month.APRIL;

        // Get the month number
        System.out.println("Month #: " + month.getValue());

    }
}
```